# EF5: Load only related records, that are not deleted (IsDeleted = false)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, dbcontext

I am using EF5 Code First with self-tracking entities. How can I ensure, that only the related Product nodes of my Category entity are loaded, that are `IsDeleted == false`? I created the Model using the EF Power Tools and would like to store this extra query condition somewhere in the model mapping classes (in `MyContext : DbContext` or `ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>`). Every time I access the `Products` attribute of the `Category` class, only the products that are not deleted should be loaded. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your context you can add a method which returns your query:

```
public class MyContext: DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Entity> Entities {get;set;}

    public IQueryable<Entity> NonDeletedEntities()
    {
        return this.Entities.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false);
    }
}
```

Now you can consume that query and aggregate it with other conditions and they will both be queried

```
new MyContext().NonDeletedEntities().Where(e => e.Name == "Philippe");

//is the same as
new MyContext().Entities.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false && e.Name == "Philippe");
```

**UPDATE**

As noted in your comment, If you want to access non-deleted products from the category entity

```
public class Category 
{
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public IQueryable<Products> NonDeletedProductts() 
    {
        return this.Products.Where(e => e.IsDeleted == false);
    }
}
```

I have not tested this, but it should work.

Comment: Thanks. Is this the common way to pre-filter soft-deleted entities? I would have prefered if the query could be specified somewhere in the relation between the two entities, e.g. in here `this.HasRequired(t => t.Category).WithMany(t => t.Products).HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId);`. The way you describe it, I have to query the `IsDeleted` attribute every time I access the `Products` attribute in the `Category` class.